# Universal unit conversion application

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, offline, calculator

### Description

I would like to discover an universal application that can convert between all 
kind of units such as time units, file-size and internet transfer-rate units (informatic units), measurement units, powering units, etc.

### Conditions

- Free.
- For Windows.
- A desktop app with Graphical user interface (not a Windows Store app).
- With informatic units conversion available

  ( required: from bit to megabit, byte to terabyte )
- With Spanish translation (to understand the unit namings).
- Not too scientific/advanced/complicated.

  ( user-friendly, for "dumbs", with easy conversion options. )
- Usable offline

Answer (score 3):

You can use Calculator that comes with Windows (View > Unit Conversion), but it doesn't convert to Spanish (unless you change your OS language) and it doesn't convert megabytes.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you have Windows 10 you can also use Cortona!

Answer (score 2):

I use two programs obtained from PortableApps.com:

- [Converber](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/converber_portable) (official website [here](http://www.xyntec.com/converber.htm))
- [ConvertAll](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/convertall_portable) (official website [here](http://convertall.bellz.org/))

They are Windows programs and they both provide a translation in Spanish. Both have at least some of the data unit translations you want. They are completely offline, stand alone applications. Both are free and fairly small (1MB and 10MB installed).

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Frink:

https://www.futureboy.us/frinkdocs/

It has offline unit conversion, a GUI, and built-in translation.

[image: Frink session, including conversions from bit to megabit, byte to terabyte and "megawatt" to Spanish ("megavatios")]

(The translation does require an internet connection, though.)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but is not what I expected, the user need to know the exact name of the units because the UI doesn't provide any control element with a list of units where to choose them ( ...what the hell their developers were thinking about that? ), I think that behavior of the design lack is because this tool is intended to be ran from command-line passing parameters then the app just returns the result of the conversion, then is not any user friendly, I need to write it all in the textboxes. Thankyou anyways really!

Answer (score 1):

[Free Converter](http://www.online-unit-converter.com/software-download/)

Here's a keeper I always keep with me wherever I go. I have the portable version with me so I can easily guess some basic conversions such as Imperial to Metric, and also to guess an estimated download time using manual rate inputs.

On the negative side the portable version has no translations.

There's also an android like app that allows us to input manual data rates.

[(Wopnersoft) Unit Converter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wopnersoft.unitconverter)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I unpacked their InnoSetup installer and it just is a single exe (a portable exe), there is no translations at all on the installable version.